# Why dbca giving error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: oracle12c, xming, dbca

After doing the configuraton on Putty for X11. When I am running dbca I am getting the following error:

```
[oracle@XYZ bin]$ dbca
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
```

From command promt i have already run the command for Xming:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow -ac
```

Answer (score 0):

run this, export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
after that, run dbca